# left join not getting expected data - returns inaccurate result

Tags: mysql

I am facing issue when trying retrieve some fields from table using left join.

Table 1 has - column reportno, slno, and desc
Table 2 has - Column report no, slno and parameters

Now i would like to retrieve all values from table1 for specific report no and and corresponding  parameters from table2. My expected result is shown below.
that means it should get all row for matching repno from table 1 and also get paramaters by matching repno and slno

```js
/*table2 data*/
repno   slno  parameter 
M100001 2     TypeRating 
M100001 1     Type&Rating
```

```js
select
qc_item_list.i_rep_no,
qc_item_list.slno,
qc_item_list.ITEM_DESC,
qc_insp.parameters
from qc_item_list
left join qc_insp
on qc_item_list.I_REP_NO = qc_insp.I_REP_NO
WHERE qc_item_list.i_rep_no = 'M100001'
ORDER BY qc_item_list.slno
```

Comment: ...and what is your actual output, if not what you want?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I am getting only one parameter in all rows outcome. but i may have case like there wont be specific slno. for example i have repno 1001 that has slno from 1 to 10. but in table 2 i have parameter only for slno 1 and 2 . rest 3 - 10 there will not be any row in table 2

Comment: If those `slno` numbers aren't present in your data, then they won't be in the output unless you somehow bring it in.  Please update showing your actual data.

Comment: Thanks for including some data, but what output do you actually want here?

Comment: Your current output is inconsistent with the contents of table2.  Please update your question and show us the actual contents of table2.

Comment: The only way `slno` `1` shows up three times in the result set is if it appears three times in one of the two tables.  Since it does not, this means that either you showed us the wrong data, or something else very strange is going on.

Comment: @tim: yes you are correct. even i tried for some other repno i am getting same strange o/p as 3 row for slno

Comment: @Tim: Got the result. just added another one condition to match repno also. Thanks lot for your time and support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be joining on the `slno` column, *not* the `i_rep_no` column:

```
SELECT t1.i_rep_no,
       t1.slno,
       t1.ITEM_DESC,
       COALESCE(t2.parameters, 'NA') AS parameter
FROM qc_item_list t1
LEFT JOIN qc_insp t2
    ON t1.slno     = t2.slno AND
       t1.i_rep_no = t2.i_rep_no
WHERE t1.i_rep_no = 'M100001'
ORDER BY t1.slno
```

If you're never seen/working with `COALESCE()` before, the way it works is to use the first parameter if it be not `NULL`, and to use the second parameter as a backup should the first parameter be `NULL`.  In this case, for those records in your first table which did not have a matching `slno` in the second table, the parameter would be displayed as `NA` for "not available."

Comment: But i have only one row for slno in table2, but its retrieve two rows. similarly for slno2. could you help me

Comment: I don't understand your question.  The query I gave you above should be generating the output you want.  If you'd like, I can create a demo for you.

Comment: i have edited the snippet with what i am getting now. please check

Answer (score 1):

```js
SELECT t1.i_rep_no,
       t1.slno,
       t1.ITEM_DESC,
       COALESCE(t2.parameters, 'NA') AS parameter
FROM qc_item_list t1
LEFT JOIN qc_insp t2
    ON t1.slno = t2.slno and t1.i_rep_no = t2.i_rep_no
WHERE t1.i_rep_no = 'M100001'
ORDER BY t1.slno
```

added a condition to match repno also

Comment: Why are you including your query as JavaScript code?

Answer (score -2):

Here is basic example of left join.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

You must share both tables data and your expected output , than you can get help to fix your SQL.